# fix ubuntu 22.04 lts; dock icons doesn't refresh

Tags: gnome, icons, gnome-shell-extension, dock, dash-to-dock

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in my surface laptop 3.I am having this problem where my dock icon doesn't refresh as I put the I put the gnome extension called dock to dash.I can fix this temporarily by restarting computer but there's no permanent fix that I can lookup to.You can see the configuration setting for my extension and the icon (stuck) of dock panel

[image]

[image]